# Founder or co founder?

Tags: meaning, differences

I created a website one year ago and a friend joined me on the project seven months later.
So i worked one year on it and he worked four months.

I searched on many website to understand the differences between the two words but i still not sure.

I would like to know if : 
 - i am the founder and he is a developper ?
 - i am the founder and he is the cofounder ?
 - i am a co founder and he is a co founder too ?
 - or anything else

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To *found* is to take the first steps to build something.  (See found(4), verb at [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/found?show=0&t=1413822353).)

A *founder* is someone who founds.

If more than one person is involved in a thing's creation, then everyone who participated is a *co-founder*.

In your situation, I assume first that the website launched shortly after you created it, well before your friend joined you.  Therefore, since you are the only person who took the first steps and got the site started, you are the *founder* of the website.  Your friend can be called anything you want to establish his current duties; webmaster, programmer, developer, etc.

On the other hand, if the website still has not launched and your friend is helping you through the critical process of getting it ready to launch, then he too is taking the "first steps" (although they may be some of the *last* "first steps") in creating your website.  If this is the case, then he should be considered a co-founder.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I start to understand a bit more but i still have one question : Assuming i am into the second case : "if the website still has not launched and your friend is helping ...".
Am i the founder and him the co-founder or am i also co-founder ?

Comment: Normally you would both be considered co-founders.

Comment: (But, if you really wanted to stress that you were the one with the original idea, that you were the true driving force behind the site and he just helped with some critical pieces, then you might want to call yourself the founder and call him a co-founder.)

Answer (score 1):

From Wiktionary:

> Noun
>
> founder (plural founders)
>
> One who founds, establishes, and erects; one who lays a foundation; an author; one from >whom something originates; one who endows.

and

> Prefix
>   co-
>
> together; mutually; jointly
>   partner or subordinate in an activity

therefore

> Noun
>
> cofounder (plural cofounders)
>
> One who founds something, such as an organization, together with someone else

Thus, if you founded it by yourself, you are the founder.  If you founded it with someone else you are both cofounders.

From what you've described, I would opt to say you are the founder.  You could call your a friend a developer, or depending on their role you could also use 'admin', 'moderator', 'webmaster' and more.